# Sharepoint 2013 task mark as complete layout issues

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation

I have issues in mark as complete task in my Sharepoint 2013 Foundation. My master page is the default, i just change the colores in interface.

See the image bellow.

[image]
The image has gray background and i can not see all dots in complete square fill.

Any ideias guys?

Thanks

Comment: Hi , where's the brown background and the complete square in the above image?

Comment: Gray square sorry.